# Ext.device.Camera.capture doesn't work on sencha touch 2.4.1 and cordova 2.9.1

Tags: cordova, extjs, camera, touch, capture

I'm using the Ext.device.Camera.capture function in my sencha application with cordova for ios but it doesn't work, the camera doesn't show up.

In app.js I have 'Ext.device.Camera' in requires

Here's the code

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
        success: function(image) {
            console.log(image);
        },
        failure: function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("Errore", "Errore nel salvataggio della foto, per favore riprovare.");
        },
        quality: 85,
        width: 1280,
        height: 1713,
        destination: 'file',
        encoding: 'jpg'
});
```

n console log I get 'http://www.sencha.com/img/sencha-large.png'

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to uncomment the cordova importing line in app.json